# Which features should I choose, fast overfitting ones or slow convergence ones?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, feature-selection, overfitting, importance

I'm doing an audio/speech classification project. For the input features, I used two sets of features to find out which ones are better.

**Feature set 1 (Normalized spectrogram)**

```
# doesn't learn much
Epoch 54/56
Learning rate for epoch 54 is 1e-05.
375/375 [==============================] - 174s 463ms/step - loss: 2.8364 - acc: 0.3759 - val_loss: 3.2643 - val_acc: 0.3017
Epoch 55/56
Learning rate for epoch 55 is 1e-05.
375/375 [==============================] - 173s 462ms/step - loss: 2.8400 - acc: 0.3762 - val_loss: 3.1798 - val_acc: 0.3095
Epoch 56/56
Learning rate for epoch 56 is 1e-05.
375/375 [==============================] - 173s 460ms/step - loss: 2.8226 - acc: 0.3808 - val_loss: 3.0965 - val_acc: 0.3253
```

Here, the accuracy is not very high after 50 epochs but the validation metrics match closely.

**Feature set 2 (Normalized mfcc + pncc + gfcc)**

```
# overfitted, but more chances to improve
Epoch 46/100
Learning rate for epoch 46 is 1e-05.
375/375 [==============================] - 1259s 3s/step - loss: 0.9786 - acc: 0.9383 - val_loss: 3.4679 - val_acc: 0.2917
Epoch 47/100
Learning rate for epoch 47 is 1e-05.
375/375 [==============================] - 1118s 3s/step - loss: 0.9776 - acc: 0.9384 - val_loss: 3.4715 - val_acc: 0.2876
Epoch 48/100
Learning rate for epoch 48 is 1e-05.
375/375 [==============================] - 1141s 3s/step - loss: 0.9663 - acc: 0.9433 - val_loss: 3.4641 - val_acc: 0.2886
Epoch 49/100
Learning rate for epoch 49 is 1e-05.
375/375 [==============================] - 1215s 3s/step - loss: 0.9630 - acc: 0.9438 - val_loss: 3.4613 - val_acc: 0.2920
```

This model converges better with reaching around 94% accuracy, but the validation metrics are low suggesting a strong overfitting.

**N.B:** I'm using an efficientnet b2 for the experiment.

In such a scenario, which feature set should I use to reach more reliable and better results?

Comment: How important is it to be correct? Perhaps [tag:regularization] will reduce the degree of overfitting.

Comment: Model two is really not good with that level of overfitting. It suggests the feature set it's finding is local to the training data. Any reason you can't use both feature sets. +1 to Sycorax as well; regularization and dropout are probably going to help a lot.

Comment: Yeah, that what I was thinking, choosing 2 and using regularization, dropout, and augmentation to penalize the model. It's possible to merge them, but the dimension of these features vary a lot, so I need to resize them which may add distortion to some feature (s).